# Ordering Mechanism in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a matter in PHP & Mysql Project.

Simply, I have two tables project and project features,

Every project has as specific features.

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE projects_features (
   projectId INT NOT NULL,
   name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   value varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   weight INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO projects VALUES (NULL,'project1');

INSERT INTO projects VALUES (NULL,'project2');

INSERT INTO projects_features VALUES (1,'Feature1','Feature1 Value',1);

INSERT INTO projects_features VALUES (2,'Feature2','Feature2 Value',2);

INSERT INTO projects_features VALUES (1,'Feature3','Feature3 Value',3);

INSERT INTO projects_features VALUES (2,'Feature4','Feature4 Value',4);

INSERT INTO projects_features VALUES (1,'Feature5','Feature5 Value',5);
```

I Get the Project features by:

```
SELECT * FROM projects_features WHERE projectId = 1 ORDER BY weight ASC;
```

So the bigger weight will be down and lower weight will be Up.

Now,
In My View I have move up and move down buttons, so I can re-sort project features.

I can firstly select the current item weight then select the upper item weight ,

then type two update queries to exchange the weight between the two rows,

but it's not a professional way , I don't like to use four queries.

I need to do it in one query Instead of four queries.

Can anybody help please ?

Comment: are you asking how to do a single insert stmt for the above 5?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd tackle this, assuming I've understood the question.

First, I'd add a `featureId` column to `projects_features`, and make `(projectId, featureId)` the composite primary key. This isn't actually *necessary* to my solution; it just makes the rest a whole lot easier. For the next part you need to be able to reference individual records in `projects_features`.

Next, I'd have the `Move` buttons populate an array in PHP, like

```
$update_list = array();
$update_list[i] = array(':project_id' => $proj_id,
                        ':feature_id' => $feat_id,
                        ':new_weight' => $weight);
```

Finally, I'd do the update through a PHP function that encapsulates the `UPDATE` statements, like this:

```
function updateWeights($update_array, $dbh)
{
    $sql = 'UPDATE project_features
              SET weight = :new_weight
              WHERE projectId = :project_id
                AND featureId = :feature_id'
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($update_array as $update_item)
    {
        $stmt->execute($update_item);
    }
}
```

Note I'm using PDO here; it could also be done with mysqli, although mysqli doesn't support named bind parameters so the syntax would be slightly different, something like

```
function updateWeights($update_array, $dbh)
{
    $sql = 'UPDATE project_features
              SET weight = ?
              WHERE projectId = ?
                AND featureId = ?'
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($update_array as $update_item)
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $update_item[':new_weight']);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $update_item[':project_id']);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $update_item[':feature_id']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Also note that I haven't actually run this code, and so make no representation that it is free of syntax or other errors.

I hope that helps.